# android ImageView subclass dosen't show properly

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to do some drawing with android. I have an audioplayer, which get a waveform picture from a server. And I want to draw on that picture. (Don't link me the visualiser example, that's not what I am looking for). I found this tutorial (http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html), and I made this
my subclass of View:

```
    public class WaveFormSurfaceView extends View {

Bitmap waveform = null;

public WaveFormSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public WaveFormSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context,attrs);
}

public WaveFormSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
    super(context,attrs,defStyle);
}

//copies the given waveform to a variable
public void setWaveForm(Bitmap b) {

    waveform = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getWidth(),
            b.getHeight(), b.getConfig());
    // copy the pixel to it
    int[] allpixels = new int[b.getHeight() * b.getWidth()];
    b.getPixels(allpixels, 0, b.getWidth(), 0, 0,
            b.getWidth(), b.getHeight());
    waveform.setPixels(allpixels, 0, b.getWidth(), 0, 0,
            b.getWidth(), b.getHeight());


}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Create a paint object for us to draw with, and set our drawing color
    // to blue.
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setAlpha(50);

    // draws the rectangle

    if(waveform!=null){
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, (float)0.5 * waveform.getWidth(),
            waveform.getHeight(), paint);
    }else{
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0,50,
                50, paint);
    }
    //mImageView.setImageBitmap(map);
}

 }
```

Here is my activity:

```
    public class AudioPlayerActivity extends Activity{
// Hardcoded parameters for the Verba demo server
    private static final String ServerURL = "http://something.com";
    private static final String MediaPath = "C:\\path\\media\\";

    // Player user interface elements
    private Button mBtnPlay;
    private WaveFormSurfaceView mImageView;

    //private ImageView mImageView;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private TextView mCurrentPos;
    private TextView mEndPos;

    private Bitmap originalWaveForm;





    // THIS IS THE MEDIAPLAYER (has no UI, only loads and plays the audio)
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    // HTTP URL for the audio waveform PNG picture
    private String getWaveformURL(String pCallURL) {
        return ServerURL + ":8089/a?" + MediaPath + pCallURL
                + "?10000200240240240123023048240240240240240240";
    }

    // HTTP URL for the audio transcoded to MP3 format
    private String getMediaURL(String pCallURL) {
        return ServerURL + ":10100/getMedia?file=" + MediaPath + pCallURL
                + "&format=mp3";
    }

    // Downloads the waveform image outside of the main GU thread
    private class DownloadWaveformTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                        getWaveformURL(myCallURL))
                        .getContent());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            //mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            //setWaveForm(result);
            mImageView.setWaveForm(result);
        }
    }



    // Updates the seekbar outside of the main GU thread, started only after
    // MediaPlayer exists
    private class SeekBarUpdater extends Thread {
        float p=0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final SimpleDateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.SSS");
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            int currentPosition = 0;
            final int total = mMediaPlayer.getDuration(); // //returns in msec,
                                                            // final because we
                                                            // will use in the
                                                            // runnable

            // UI update must happen on the UI thread, so we post our actions
            // there in a runnable
            mCurrentPos.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(total);
                    mEndPos.setText(tf.format(calendar.getTime()));
                    mSeekBar.setMax(total);
                }
            });

            while (mMediaPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                    currentPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(); // returns
                                                                            // in
                                                                            // msec
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }

                // we are roughly adjusting for delays due to the thread
                // communication
                // currentPosition -= 100;
                // if (currentPosition < 0 ) currentPosition = 0;
                final int currPosition = currentPosition; // final because we
                                                            // will use in the
                                                            // runnable

                p=(float)currentPosition/(float)total;

                // UI update must happen on the UI thread, so we post our
                // actions there in a runnable
                mCurrentPos.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(currPosition);
                        mCurrentPos.setText(tf.format(calendar.getTime()));
                        mSeekBar.setProgress(currPosition);
                        System.out.println("pecent="+p);
                        drawRectOnWaveForm(p);
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }




    String myCallURL;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of MyFragment that will be initialized
     * with the given arguments.
     */
    static MediaPlayerFragment newInstance(CharSequence url) {
        MediaPlayerFragment f = new MediaPlayerFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putCharSequence("call_url", url);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    /**
     * During creation, if arguments have been supplied to the fragment
     * then parse those out.
     */
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String value1 = extras.getString("call_url");
            if(value1!=null){
                myCallURL=value1;
            }
        }



        setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
        System.out.println("AudioPlayerActivity setContentView, mycallurl: "+myCallURL);

        DownloadWaveformTask task = new DownloadWaveformTask();
        task.execute();

        // part of the player UI
        //mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mImageView = (WaveFormSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mBtnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        mCurrentPos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentPos);
        mEndPos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endPos);
        Button drawButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);





        //
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser) {
                    // we only update the player if the change comes from a user
                    // action
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }
        });

        // IMPORTANT
        // - The DownloadWaveformTask part should go into the initialization of
        // the player fragment
        // - currently we are NOT handling currently the end of playback
        // situations, we should
        // - currently we are NOT releasing the MediaPlayer resource, we should
        // when a fragment closes
        mBtnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mMediaPlayer.pause();
                        mBtnPlay.setText("Play");
                    } else {
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                        mBtnPlay.setText("Pause");
                    }
                } else {


                    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                    // this updates the seekbar as the buffering happens
                    mMediaPlayer
                            .setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp,
                                        int percent) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    mSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress((int) (mSeekBar
                                            .getMax() * percent / 100));
                                }
                            });

                    try {
                        final String lMediaURL = getMediaURL(myCallURL);
                        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(lMediaURL);
                        mMediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for
                                                // buffering, etc)
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    mBtnPlay.setText("Pause");

                    // we start the thread that updates the seekbar, based on
                    // the state of the player
                    SeekBarUpdater thread = new SeekBarUpdater();
                    thread.start();
                }
            }
        });

        // Close button
        Button closeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closebtn);
        closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO ha megy a lejátszás, megállítjuk
                if(mMediaPlayer!=null){
                    if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    }
                }
                finish();
            }

        });
        //myCallURL = getArguments().getString("call_url");
        //myCallURL = savedInstanceState.getString("call_url");

        //int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL;
        //int theme = android.R.style.Theme_Dialog;
        //setStyle(style, theme);

    }

}
```

Here is the mediaplayer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="center"
>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <adam.czibere.WaveFormSurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:thumb="@drawable/progress_fill" />

    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentPos"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="00:00.000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/endPos"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="00:00.000" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Play" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Close" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

And this is the image I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/HULyi.png

My problems are, where is all the other widget? Buttons, etc? And if I get it correctly, when I inflate the layout, the waveform image is not downloada yet? how can I tell to draw it, when it is downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override onMeasure() in WaveFormSurfaceView.

Comment: I don't know logic of your app, I think you can call invalidate() for redraw view.